# Alias title in joomla 2.5 link

Tags: joomla-2.5, multilingual

I know Joomla! 2.5 is out of date but I need a help. 
I have a search plugin and I'm using 2 languages. The problem is that every time I'm using the 2nd language, the result link from the search plugin is using article's alias from the 1st language (where it should be using the 2nd language).

I found that this is the script that handle the link:

```
$articles[$key]->href = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->slug, $article->catslug);
```

I've tried to change this to:

```
$articles[$key]->href = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->slug, $article->catslug, $article->language);<br>
```

But still have no result

Can anybody help please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A good pratice for this work is:

1. You need 2 articles, each article In your respective language;
2. Each article need selected the correspondent language.

If you have one article for "all languages" this problem you describe will be occour.

I holpe this helps.

Comment: Thanks Max. Yes I have made 2 articles, and both have different alias title. Every thing work ok and I can switch the language with no problem. The only problem is that every time I search, the result title using alias title from language 1 only. Even when I do the search from language 2 page, the result still using link with alias title from language 1.

Comment: it sounds like something that needs to be addressed in the search plugin. Which plugin is it?